# Why is the set of functions from the naturals to the rationals a subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N \times \mathbb Q)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Explain why the set of functions from the naturals to the rationals is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q})$?

Give an example to show that the set of functions from the naturals to the rationals is not equal to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q})$.

---

#### Context

We say the relation $f \subset (A ∪ B)\times (A ∪ B)$ is a a function from $A$ to B if:

1. $\operatorname{dom}(f) = A$ and $\operatorname{ran}(f) ⊆ B$
2. for every $a ∈ A$ there is exactly one $b ∈ B$ such that $(a, b) ∈ f$. We denote this by $f : A \to B$.

We were not given the definition for $P(\mathbb N \times \mathbb Q)$.

I don't understand what it means when they say "the set of functions from the naturals to the rationals", and I also don't know what the power set of $(\mathbb N \times \mathbb Q)$ is.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: This would not be a question in for example calculus, it would be a question involving the very formal set-theoretic definition of a function.  Please provide the definition given in your course/textbook/whatever.

Comment: I literally have no idea where to start. I don't understand what it means when they say "the set of functions from the naturals to the rationals", and I also don't know what the power set of (N x Q) even is. We were never taught anything like this.

Comment: What is your definition of a function? What is your definition of an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: What definition of a function were you given?

Comment: This would be the class definition of a function.
We say the relation f ⊆ (A ∪ B) × (A ∪ B) is a a function from A to B if:
1. dom(f) = A and ran(f) ⊆ B
2. for every a ∈ A there is exactly one b ∈ B such that (a, b) ∈ f.
We denote this by f : A → B. We generally write (a, b) ∈ f as f(a) = b if f is a function

Comment: With this definition of a function that you just gave, here is a hint for the first part: consider all such pairs $(a,b)$ in $f$.

Comment: We were not given the definition for P(N × Q).

Answer (score 1):

Well, a function $f:A \to B$ is just a subset of the set $A \times B$. Remember that a mapping $f: a \in A \to b \in B$ is at the most basic level just an ordered pair $(a,b)$.

From that, answering the first question should follow reasonably quickly.

Once that is realized, giving an answer to the second question is easy. Remember that a function maps every input to **one and only one** output. But the powerset of $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q})$ will include all possible combinations of Naturals and Rationals. Here's an example of taking the cartesian product, just to emphasize the point:

$$\{a,b,c\} \times \{1,2,3\} = \{(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),\ldots,(c,2),(c,3)\}$$

So by definition of the powerset, you'll have elements such as $\{(1,1),(1,\frac 12),(1, \frac 23),\ldots\}$ which clearly aren't functions because they imply that $1$ is mapped to $1$, and $1$ is mapped to $\frac 12$, etc. which violates the rule that every input is mapped to just one output.

---

I just read your (the OP's) comments on your question. If you weren't taught any of this stuff, here's a primer:

- Naturals $(\mathbb{N})$: the natural numbers. That's $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$
- Rationals $(\mathbb{Q})$: the rational numbers. That's numbers like $0,1,-1,2,-2,\frac 1 2, - \frac 1 2, \frac 2 3, - \frac 2 3$, etc. These are **all** the numbers that you can express as fractions.
- Power set ($\mathcal{P})$: the set of all subsets of a set. For example, $\mathcal{P}(a,b,c)$ = $\{ \emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$
- Cartesian Product ($\times$): all possible combinations of the elements of two sets: $\{a,b\} \times \{1,2\} = \{(a,1),(a,2),(b,1),(b,2)\}$.
- Note that sets are unordered: $\{1,2,3\} = \{3,2,1\}$
- And tuples are ordered: $(a,b) \neq (b,a)$.
- Functions are a little bit complicated. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) for a reasonably thorough explanation.

Comment: The first sentence is a bit strange.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure what I was thinking. Corrected.